# sphinx-quickstart fails

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm really having trouble getting to the first rung of the Sphinx tutorial ladder.

I need to implement Sphinx for work projects.  We are starting fresh with a new code-base (Django) for a large project.

I've been tasked with setting up our new code-base (automated unit tests, documentation, etc).  I've used doxygen in the past (mostly for C++ and a bit for Python).  I've read a lot of sources saying Sphinx is the best for Python and I'd like to give it a try.

The problem is that I can't even seem to get through the first step of the tutorial - `sphinx-quickstart`.

I am able to tab-complete the command so I assume it's installed correctly.  (maybe not?)

Here is the error I get:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/sphinx-quickstart", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
  pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: docutils>=0.7
```

I've tried to find some online info related to this problem but I haven't been able to find anything useful.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing docutils, or you have an older version;

> pkg_resources.**DistributionNotFound: docutils>=0.7**

Are you sure it's installed?

Comment: It appears you are correct about this.  I installed docutils and ran into more problems.  I suspect D.Shawley is correct...Sphinx did not install correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
pip install --force-reinstall sphinx
```

It looks like the Sphinx package was not correctly installer or, more correctly, it's dependencies are not currently installed.  If you do not have super-user privilege, then find an administrator to install or use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.org/) instead.

I highly recommend using *virtualenv* whenever possible since it does not touch the stuff in `/usr/local` or any of the Python `.../site-packages` directories.  I will warn you that it is rather addictive :-)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I think I need to take a step back and ensure I get sphinx installed correctly.